# Is it possible to embed bokeh charts with hover tool in PowerPoint?

Tags: python, powerpoint, bokeh

I am going to embed bokeh charts into PowerPoint (Office 365) using Python. The charts must have at least hover tool stating x and y values. I think there are 2 ways of implementation both of which don't give solution to me:

1. save the charts in html format and embed them in PowerPoint - I don't know if there is a way to save the open html file (not the link) in the PowerPoint.
2. save the chart in svg format - but the hover tool is missing there.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You can embed html files in PowerPoint, but this will just be a clickable object, which I don't think is what you want. PowerPoint can't render html like a web browser would.